# Implement micro service with micro front end using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, microservices, micro-frontend

I have a huge application which was developed in vb.net.

Our goal to convert this application to C# micro services, but in incremental manner.

So what ever new functionality that we are going to add to the existing application, we are planning to create them as a separate Micro Service with micro front end UI.

Since these are small api's with UI, I am trying to understand whether we can implement this API + UI in a single ASP.NET MVC project as a web component.

I tried 2 options:

1. Created an ASP.NET MVC application and added angular to same project. Is this better way to mix MVC and Angular in a single project?
2. I tried creating a sample ASP.NET MVC application with razor ui. But didn't understand how I can use this as a microfrontend component.

I am good in ASP.NET MVC and C#, but not that great in Angular. So planning to create microfrontend component in ASP.NET MVC razor.

Is it possible to do this? As I have to use this micro ui component in vb.net, I need this to be generated as js file to use further.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but explaining how (properly) would take more words than are available in Stack Overflow's Answer box. There are several frameworks that help bring micro-frontends to reality, like https://single-spa.js.org/ and you can use ASP.NET MVC to to do the aggregation of different UIs on the server and show them as one to the client.

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you also go through the option 1, whether is it correct way?